# How do I simplify an embedded sub-expression without affecting other sub-expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression which is very large and which has several sub-expressions with head `Conjugate`. What I want to do is simplify the `Conjugate[...]` sub-expressions without affecting other sub-expressions.

The first method I considered is was the `Transformationfunctions` option of `Simplify`. I wrote:

```
Simplify[expr,Transformationfunctions->{Conjugate}]
```

Well, `Conjugate` does indeed disappear, but the result is wrong. For example (with `$Assumptions` set so all variables are considered real)

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[
   t1 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky]) + 
   I t1 (-2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ky/2] + Sin[ky])],
   Transformationfunctions->{Conjugate}]
```

gives

```
t1 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky]) + 
I t1 (-2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ky/2] + Sin[ky])
```

The second method I considered is to use `ComplexExpand //@ Conjugate`. Since all the variables in my expression are declared real variables, `Conjugate[expr]` will become `ComplexExpand //@ Conjugate[expr]`. To make such this substitution, I could use search-and-replace and evaluate-in-place, but as I have said, the expression is large, so I don't want to do it that way. Instead I did the following:

```
largeexpr /. Conjugate -> ComplexExpand //@ Conjugate
```

But this did not work.

Here `largeexpr` is an expression containing sub-expressions with head `Conjugate`. For example,

```
Sqrt[t1^2]+Conjugate[
   t1 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky]) + 
   I t1 (-2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ky/2] + Sin[ky])]
```

So can anyone point out what I did wrong? Or suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

The `TransformationFunctions` used in `Simplify` should be functions that *transform* an expression without *changing* it. So things like `Expand` and `Factor` are fine, but `Conjugate` should not be used because `Conjugate[z]` is not the same as `z`.

I think what you are trying to do in your second method is to apply `ComplexExpand` on any subexpression with head `Conjugate`. Something like this:

```
expr = Sqrt[t1^2] + 
  Conjugate[
   t1 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky]) + 
    I t1 (-2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ky/2] + Sin[ky])];

expr /. c_Conjugate :> ComplexExpand[c]

(* Sqrt[t1^2] + t1 (2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Cos[ky/2] + Cos[ky]) - 
 I t1 (-2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] kx)/2] Sin[ky/2] + Sin[ky]) *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! Your solution to my second method is perfect !!
But about TransformationFunctions, I still have doubt. For example I want to simplify an expression only use Expand and Together. How should I write? I've tried write like **Simplify[(1 + x)^6, TransformationFunctions -> {Expand}]** (use only expand), but it didn't work.

Comment: @user15964, it did work, but remember that `Simplify` aims to reduce the complexity of the expression. In this case, `Expand` *increases* the complexity, and the so lowest complexity expression `Simplify` can find is the one you started with.